# How configure Achiles work with entity methods properly?

Tags: java, cassandra, persistence

I use [Achilles](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles) library for working with cassandra database. The problem is when I create entity method that effects fields Achilles do not "see" these changes. See example below.

```
import info.archinnov.achilles.persistence.PersistenceManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AhilesTest {
    private static final UUID ID = UUID.fromString("083099f6-e423-498d-b810-d6c564228724");

    //This is achilles persistence manager
    @Autowired
    private PersistenceManager persistenceManager;

    public void test () {
        //user creation and persistence
        User toInsert = new User();
        toInsert.setId(ID);
        toInsert.setName("name");
        toInsert.setVersion(0l);
        persistenceManager.insert(toInsert);

        //find user
        User  user = persistenceManager.find(User.class, id);
        user.changeName("newName");
        persistenceManager.update(user);

        User updatedUser = persistenceManager.find(User.class, id);
        //here old "name" value is returned
        updatedUser.getName();
    }

    public class User {
        private UUID id; 
        private String name;
        private long version;

        public void changeName (String newName) {
            this.name = newName;
            this.version++;
        }

        //getters and setters are omited
    }
}
```

`user.changeName("newName");` do not affect entity and "old" values are persisted. For my opinion (I have seen debug call stack) this happens because actual User entity is wrapper with Achilles proxy which react to gettter/setter calls. Also when I replace `changeName`: call to direct getter/setter invocation -  `user.setName("newName"); user.setVersion(user.getVersion()+1);` updating became work.

So why it is happens and is there a way to configure Achilles to react of non getter/setter methods calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before do any actions with `user` you should get user proxy from `info.archinnov.achilles.persistence.PersistenceManager` and only after that use setters/getters for modification with 'user' entity.

```
User user = persistenceManager.getProxy(User.class, UUID.fromString(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the setter methods explicitly.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/Dirty-Checking), it intercepts the setter methods only.

```
"As a consequence of this design, internal calls inside an entity cannot be intercepted 
and will escape dirty check mechanism. It is thus recommended to change state of the 
entities using setters"
```

It is probably a design choice from achilles, and I suggest you raise it as an issue on the [issues](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/issues) page, so it may receive some attention from the author.